# Avoiding Syntax Error: Unknown font tag 'Helvetica'

Tags: python

I have been getting this error message printed when I run my scripts via terminal as CLI. The scripts parse pdf files and convert them to a csv file with fields extracted.

However I don't see this error printed when I run the script on jupyter notebook.

The error doesn't seem to cause any issue or stop the code. It just prints this error on the console.

If we can't fix this error, how do I avoid it getting printed on console? I know I can suppress warnings via Warning module,

```
import warnings

#ignore by message
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="RuntimeWarning ....")
```

but how to suppress printing this particular error only on console?

Comment: You aren't getting a SyntaxError if it's a warning. A SyntaxError generally means your program *failed to compile*, let alone run

Comment: but program runs. It doesn't stop.

Comment: here is what getting printed in console when I run the script. It doesn't stop the program and it goes and does further task. Just this message is getting printed. 

Syntax Error: Unknown font tag 'Helvetica'

Comment: I don't think this is a Python error message, rather, it's some error message from some library that is being called underneath the hood of whatever library you are using.

Comment: yes. I believe this is coming from pdftotext. How do I prevent python to print it out on console